# How to set search option on search-bar for multiple pages in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

1. I have a bundle of data coming from database. It is like 4550 page. I have a search bar, when I type some thing it show only data of current page, if he can't find from that page then it show nothing instead of searching to other page.
   Here is my code tell me where is my fault?
   and also I am using filter method here. If it not work then please suggest me what should I do?
2. And also there is pagination, it is working perfect but when I am on other page after refresh it takes me to to first page instead of that page

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import LikeButton from "../components/LikeButton";
import FirstHeader from "../accets/head1.jpg";
import SecondHeader from "../accets/head2.jpg";
import ThirdHeader from "../accets/head2.jpg";
import { TbCricket } from "react-icons/tb";
import { TbBallTennis } from "react-icons/tb";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import { BsFillPersonLinesFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { AiTwotoneLike } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiFillMessage } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiFillCalendar } from "react-icons/ai";

const Players = () => {
  const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const [currentPlayers, setCurrentPlayers] = useState(null);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  const [playersOffset, setPlayersOffset] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    console.log("dummy");
    axios
      .get(
        `http://192.168.18.8/goc-backend/api/web/index.php/v1/player/?expand=specialitiesInfo,relations,specialitiesInfo.battingStyle,specialitiesInfo.fieldingStyle,specialitiesInfo.bowlingStyle,teams.team,cricketInfo,playersNews.news,playersGallery.image,playersVideos.video,playersComments,sports?page=${page}`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response", response.data.items);
        setPageCount(response.data._meta.pageCount);
        setPlayerData((prevState) => [...response.data.items]);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(response.data.items);
        return response.data.items;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [page, query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const endOffset = playersOffset + 8;
    setCurrentPlayers(playerData);
  }, [playerData, playersOffset]);

  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
    const newOffset = (event.selected * 8) % playerData.length;
    console.log("yeeeeƒß", event);
    setPage(event.selected + 1);
  };
  console.log("data: ", playerData);

  return (
    <div>
      <style>{"body { background-color: #1A2127 }"}</style>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-1"></div>
          <div className="col-md-10">
            <div
              id="myCarousel"
              className="carousel slide"
              data-bs-ride="carousel"
            >
              <div className="carousel-indicators">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-target="#myCarousel"
                  data-bs-slide-to="0"
                  class="active"
                  aria-label="Slide 1"
                  aria-current="true"
                ></button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-target="#myCarousel"
                  data-bs-slide-to="1"
                  aria-label="Slide 2"
                  className=""
                ></button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-target="#myCarousel"
                  data-bs-slide-to="2"
                  aria-label="Slide 3"
                  className=""
                ></button>
              </div>
              <div className="carousel-inner">
                <div className="carousel-item active">
                  <img
                    className="bd-placeholder-img"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    src={FirstHeader}
                    alt="header1"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
                    focusable="false"
                  ></img>

                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="carousel-caption text-start">
                      <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                      <p>
                        Some representative placeholder content for the first
                        slide of the carousel.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <a className="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">
                          Sign up today
                        </a>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <img
                    className="bd-placeholder-img"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    src={SecondHeader}
                    alt="header2"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
                    focusable="false"
                  ></img>

                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                      <p>
                        Some representative placeholder content for the second
                        slide of the carousel.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <a className="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">
                          Learn more
                        </a>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <img
                    className="bd-placeholder-img"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    src={ThirdHeader}
                    alt="header3"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
                    focusable="false"
                  ></img>

                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="carousel-caption text-end">
                      <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                      <p>
                        Some representative placeholder content for the third
                        slide of this carousel.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <a className="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">
                          Browse gallery
                        </a>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button
                className="carousel-control-prev"
                type="button"
                data-bs-target="#myCarousel"
                data-bs-slide="prev"
              >
                <span
                  className="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
              <button
                className="carousel-control-next"
                type="button"
                data-bs-target="#myCarousel"
                data-bs-slide="next"
              >
                <span
                  className="carousel-control-next-icon"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="heading-h3"> </div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row ">
            <div className="col-md-1"></div>
            <div className="col-md-10 ">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="item-body h3-r">
                  <h1>All Players </h1>
                  <div className="search">
                  <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          label="Search Player"
        />
      </div>
     </div>
         {/* setQuery(event.target.value) */}
      {playerData
        
          .map((player) => {
                  const {
                    id,
                    profile_photo,
                    full_name,
                    country,
                    sport_id,
                    speciality_id,
                    dob,
                  } = player;
                  return (
                    <div className="col-10 pl-r col-md-3 mt-21">
                      <div key={id}>
                        <div className="card">
                          <img
                            src="https://www.fctwente.nl/assets/Bestanden/Berichten/EK-OranjeLeeuwinnen-plaatsen-zich-voor-kwartfinale/55351919_ORANGE_PICTURES_FocusFillWyItMC4xMiIsIi0wLjc5IiwxMjgwLDU2MF0__FocusFillWyItMC4yNiIsIi0wLjUzIiwyODgsMTgwXQ.jpeg"
                            class="card-img-top"
                            alt="..."
                          />
                          <div className="card-body">
                            <h4 className="card-title">{full_name} </h4>
                          </div>
                          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush ul-contry">
                            <li className="list-group-item li-contry">
                              <span>
                                <TbCricket />
                              </span>
                              <span>{sport_id}</span>
                            </li>
                            <li className="list-group-item">
                              <span className="li-date ">
                              {speciality_id}
                              </span>
                              {/* <span className="li-contbtn"> {country}</span> */}
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li className="list-group-item">
                              <BsFillPersonLinesFill />
                              <div className="li-li2">
                                <span className="li-span1">Age</span>
                                <span className="li-span2">21</span>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="list-group-item">
                              <AiTwotoneLike />
                              <div className="li-li2">
                                <span className="li-span1">Likes</span>
                                <span className="li-span2">1.7k</span>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="list-group-item">
                              <AiFillMessage />
                              <div className="li-li2">
                                <span className="li-span1">Comments</span>
                                <span className="li-span2">1.4k</span>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div className="card-body cd-bottom list-group">
                            <ul className="list-group-flush">
                              <li className="list-group-item">
                                <div className="li-li2">
                                  <span className="li-span2">{country}</span>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="#" className="card-link">
                              <LikeButton />
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
              <div className="paginate">
                <div className="pagination">
                  <ReactPaginate
                    breakLabel="..."
                    nextLabel="next >"
                    onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={2}
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                    previousLabel="< previous"
                    renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                    breakClassName={"page-item"}
                    breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    pageClassName={"page-item"}
                    pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    previousClassName={"page-item"}
                    previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    nextClassName={"page-item"}
                    nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    activeClassName={"active"}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
              
};


export default Players;
```
`
````

Comment: This is too much code , can you tell us in short part what you want?

Comment: Search bar functionality and pagination